# Find the Information of USB Devices In C++

Tags: usb, c++

I need to list existing USB hub and the devices connected in the hub using my C++ program.

I can able to print the USB Hub and devices connected in hub from terminal using the commands

```
lsusb
lsusb -v
```

I want to use that feature in my C++ program.

How I can do this programmatically. Is there any C++ classes available to use in my Qt application.

Comment: use libusb, search here: there was a similar question recently. [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279796/linux-libusb-get-usb-device-path).

Comment: In archlinux this is in `libusb-compat` package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here the simplest analogue of `lsusb`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <usb.h>
main(){
    struct usb_bus *bus;
    struct usb_device *dev;
    usb_init();
    usb_find_busses();
    usb_find_devices();
    for (bus = usb_busses; bus; bus = bus->next)
        for (dev = bus->devices; dev; dev = dev->next){
            printf("Trying device %s/%s\n", bus->dirname, dev->filename);
            printf("\tID_VENDOR = 0x%04x\n", dev->descriptor.idVendor);
            printf("\tID_PRODUCT = 0x%04x\n", dev->descriptor.idProduct);
        }
}
```

Compile with `-lusb`

Comment: I tried it but did not worked to me. 
I am using Ubuntu OS and qt creator and I try after installing  libusb-1.0-0-dev, libusb++-0.1-4c2 etc.
where this usb.h header file come from

Comment: Finally i installed its libary file.Now I can include #include <usb.h>

But where its library file is located?

Comment: @arun kumar KS at 11:39 , So where did you find the library file?

Comment: I am not remembering but check this link. this may help you..https://github.com/libusb/libusb/issues/17

Answer (score 0):

This is Fedora, for Debian based distributions you should be able to do something similar:

- Get the package containing that program: "rpm -qif /usr/bin/lsusb" tells you it comes from the usbutils package, homepage is http://www.linux-usb.org
- Look at the sources posted there (presumably in C, it should be easy to extract what you need from there)

Alternatively:

- Find out where/how the kernel publishes the information on the USB setup, i.e. /sys/bus/usb/devices shows the whole setup
- Read up on how that information is organized (this is set up for easy parsing, so it shouldn't be too hard to handle)

A desperate solution:

- Just run the lsusb(8) program itself and get the required data from its output

BTW, consider using Python instead of C++ to write your GUI application. GUIs rarely are performance critical enough, and the savings in programmer time more than offset any efficiency losses (and the user probably won't notice them anyway).